# How do I get my PHP to return JSON, from XML

Tags: php, json

I have the following code, note I am new to working with PHP, I am successful in retrieving the data I want, it is in XML format, but I want it in JSON. I have researched this and nothing seems to be working. any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if( !function_exists("curl_init") && !function_exists("curl_setopt") && 
!function_exists("curl_exec") && !function_exists("curl_close") )
   { 
   echo "Missing Functions";
    } 
else
echo 'curl exists';
$url = 'http://www.somesite.com/blog/feed/';
$client = curl_init();
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($client);
curl_close($client);
echo $result;


?>
```

Comment: unless the particular site offers different versions of the feed (ie: xml & json ) then you'll have to download the xml and process it yourself

Comment: any suggestions, my colleaguesafter curl_close($client); code put this in.





header('Content-type: text/xml');

$result_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

echo $result_xml[0]->channel->item->asXML();




most likely you will have to loop into object of $result_xml have offered the following:

Comment: but that gave me errors

Comment: You'll need to parse the xml, create an array & then call json_encode() on it. Show some example xml output & you might get better answers

Comment: I think I may have tried something like that and I was getting errors, but I will try it again, thank you